# The command prompt can't find the .wav file which should be used for backround music

Tags: java, cmd, wav, relative-path

I want to make sure after the program (whole directory) was moved that the program still can use the .wav file which is inside the directory.
The problem is the CMD can't read the relative path of the .wav file and always come back with an error.

I tried this:

```
String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println(filePath);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filePath+"/zene.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a partial answer but please consider the following:

1. Fix the Exception errors:

   ```
   try {
       AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filePath+"/zene.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Change to the directory where the java file is located and compile `javac <filename.java>` then execute `java <filename>`